# Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'test'

Tags: c#, variables, for-loop

is there something missing here?

```
private int existb1b2(Bill b1, ArtQty artQty)
        {
            int test;
            for(int i = 0; i < b1.ArtQty.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (b1.ArtQty[i].Article.Name == artQty.Article.Name)
                    test = 0;
                else
                    test = -1;
            }
            return test;
        }
```

I got `Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'test'`

I think that `test` should be initialized.

Comment: you have no `return` statement anywhere in that function

Comment: Also, you should `break` out of the loop when you have a match.

Comment: When I use `return test`, it shows `(local variable) int test`

Comment: And use C# style naming, as in `DoesBillExistInArray`. And never use one-letter variable names. And use booleans.

Comment: When you use `return test` where? it is not in the code

Comment: @Laidback: If your code now has a different error, you now have a different question. Editing it in like this is bad form.

Comment: As that error message says, you need to initialise `test`, e.g.: `int test = 0;`

Comment: @Laidback: A better name for your method, which correctly starts with a capital letter and conveys what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems - first, you need to assign an initialize value to `test`, because there is no guarantee you will even enter the `for` loop.  This is the source of your error.

Second, you probably want to return 0 if you have a match - the way the code is written, it will actually return -1 even if a match is found unless the LAST item in your list is the match.  You are probably better off to simply return the moment a match is found, no need to iterate the rest of the items, and no local variable assignment is even required.

Try this:

```
private int existb1b2(Bill b1, ArtQty artQty)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.ArtQty.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (b1.ArtQty[i].Article.Name == artQty.Article.Name) return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Or if you just want to fix your compilation error, you could change your `int test;` line to `int test = -1;`

Comment: Additional possible improvement: in most languages, 1 is true and 0 is false. This code uses a very unusual representation of these two values by subtracting each by 1. However, in C# you would ideally use `bool` rather than int.

Comment: Agreed, bool would be better.

Comment: How if I would like to return the position? It shows the same error when I make `return i`!

Comment: Make a new question and show your code.  To return the position of the found item, wouldn't you just use `return i`?